# Performance Monitor % Processor Time metric difference between _Total and sqlservr.exe

Tags: sql-server, performance, data-collection, performance-monitor

I have SQL Server running on 32-core CPU, and I use Performance Monitor (perfmon.msc) to collect data on Processor: % Processor Time (Instance - _Total) and Process: % Processor Time (Instance - sqlservr.exe)

So for example for day 2019/07/21 (Sunday), it shows average values:

```
Processor: % Processor Time (Instance - _Total) - 3.959
Process: % Processor Time (Instance - sqlservr.exe) - 107.312
```

Why is such a difference ?

I expected sqlservr.exe to show values like 2.900 or 3.100 - something like this, but not 107.312

How to correlate _Total to sqlservr.exe ?

I am using MaxDOP limited to 8 server level setting on SQL Server, if this is any help

Comment: It's 107.312 out of 3.959.

Comment: Divide by number of cores: `SELECT 107.312/32 AS SqlServerPercentTotal;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Process: % Processor Time (Instance - sqlservr.exe)` counter takes into account all of your cores. If you divide by the cores you get an answer much similar to what you expected.

This [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx) explains it in far more detail but it uses this calculation to get the number you see:
`(No of Logical Cores * 100),  So this is going to be a calculated over a baseline of more than 100.`